# How to get my Android device's CPU and processor information programatically?

Tags: android, qualcomm

Hope you all are safe and doing well.
Currently i integrated some SDK for auto capturing the documents.SDK team now updated their minimum hardware requirements for auto capture feature,if these requirement does not meet, user have to manually capture documents.Those requirements are
1. RAM should be at least 2GB.
2. Systemt chip 
             1. Qualcomm Snapdragon 800 series, minimum 820 or equivalent.
              2. Qualcomm Snapdragon 600 series, minimum 630 or equivalent.
             3.  Qualcomm Snapdragon 700 series, minimum 710 or equivalent.
3. CPU with 
             64-bit, quad-core
2.0 GHz
How to check these configurations programmatically in Android, so that i can navigate user appropriately in my application.
Thanks in advance
Cheers

Comment: For memory, I believe this will be enough: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.MemoryInfo.html#totalMem

Comment: @CesarCastro It helped thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With this method you can retrieve the information that you need.

```
try {
    var holder = ""
    val data = arrayOf("/system/bin/cat", "/proc/cpuinfo")
    val byteArray = ByteArray(1024)
    val processBuilder = ProcessBuilder(*data)
    val process = processBuilder.start()
    val inputStream = process.inputStream

    while (inputStream.read(byteArray) != -1) {
        holder += String(byteArray)
    }

    inputStream.close()

    print(holder)
    
} catch (ex: IOException) {
    ex.printStackTrace()
}
```

Comment: This is useful but the chip of the CPU is not in the response array like Snapdragon 865 or any. Thanks for sharing